# How to pull git branch without undoing all my changes?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a git branch I'm working from and I have screwed it up. I have a bunch of local changes I made and I'm trying to put these changes and this commit into a PR but I can't do that without updating from the branch because they somehow got out of sync. So whenever I run `git status` I get

```
Your branch and 'origin/myChanges' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

And everything I've tried with the git pull just blows all of my changes away, but I need to update from the branch before I'm allowed to send the commit to the PR. I've also tried running a force push to have the branch be the same as mine (it's just a small branch I made for this feature so w little risk). I don't know how to git pull in such a way where my changes are not destroyed and blown away, I want to keep everything that is local and I don't care about anything on the branch.

Comment: [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)will solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, your steps in such a situation should be something like:

1. [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash) your local uncommitted changes.
2. Run `git fetch` to make sure your local clone knows what refs are on remote.
3. [Rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) your local branch onto `origin/myChanges`.
4. [Fix up any merge conflicts](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts) that occurred.
5. Pop your [stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash#re-applying-your-stashed-changes).
6. Fix up any merge conflicts that occurred from stash popping.
7. [Force-push with lease](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force-with-leaseltrefnamegtltexpectgt) your changes to `origin/myChanges`. If you have multiple developers working on the same branch (which you really, *really* shouldn't do since it leads to these situations), inform them that you've force-pushed.
8. Keep working on your changes, then commit and push when you're ready.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` could be helpful in such a case

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

Take a close look at the documentaton for [`git stash`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash). If I understand it right, you first stash your local changes away to get a clean state. Then you can git pull to merge remote changes of the branch. And then add the stash back again, with `git stash pop`

> Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree state.

Comment: Potential pitfall is that when you pop the stash, you will probably get merge conflicts. This is unavoidable, but readers should be aware of what comes after popping a stash .